# Name on top of two optimization problems

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, alignment

I want to write two optimization problems side by side and label each on top for future reference. I've been able to do so by using `minipage`. In order to have the labels centered with respect to the problems, I've added a third column in the array. This results in too much space within each problem and too little between problems themselves (see image).

[image]

Also, if I create `tags` (for referencing), they end up at the end of the minipage rather than on top of it.

My code (without tags) is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
 \begin{equation*}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \begin{array}{lll}
       & (I) &\\
       \text{maximize}& &\quad \mathbf{q}^\top\mathbf{1}\\
       \text{subject to}& &\quad \left(\mathbf{q}^{1/\alpha}\right)^\top\mathbf{X}\leq\mathbf{k}\\
       & &\quad \mathbf{q}\geq\mathbf{0}
    \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{equation*}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
   \begin{array}{lll}
      & (II) &\\
      \text{minimize}& &\quad \left(\mathbf{q}^{1/\alpha}\right)^\top\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}  \\
      \text{subject to} & &\quad \mathbf{q}^\top\mathbf{1}=1\\
      & &\quad \mathbf{q}\geq\mathbf{0}
   \end{array}
 \end{equation*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd have a solution for you but I wonder if the label group that is `I` and `II` should count as an equation number or something else

Comment: @Celdor Yes I'd like to be able to make references to problem I or problem II

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution.

Regarding the references, I just made a custom counter `problem` with `\refstepcounter` to add reference points for each `\label`.

As to the spacing, I wrapped the whole block within an outer narrower `minipage`, which is also centred. If spacing above and below is an issue, it might be better to use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` instead of opening ... closing `\hfill...\hspace{\fill}` around the `minipage`.

EDIT. In the code below, you can "tune" horizontal placement of both problems by changing ratio between inner `minipage`s from both `0.5\linewidth` to let's say `0.48\linewidth`/`0.52\linewidth`.

EDIT2. `\mleftright` is added to correct and improve parentheses generated by `\left(...\right)`, which are not recommended unless necessary. The siblings such as `\bigl(`, `\Bigl(` etc. (and their counter parts) should be used instead.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\newcounter{problem}
\renewcommand*{\theproblem}{\Roman{problem}}

\usepackage{showframe}   % Only to draw page borders for a reference
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
\mleftright

\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \refstepcounter{problem}\label{pr:1}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\theproblem)} \\[1.5ex]
      maximize   & $\mathbf{q}^\top\mathbf{1}$ \\
      subject to & $\left(\mathbf{q}^{1/\alpha}\right)^\top\!\mathbf{X}\leq\mathbf{k}$ \\
                 & $\mathbf{q}\geq\mathbf{0}$
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%   <--- don't remove %
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \refstepcounter{problem}\label{pr:2}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\theproblem)} \\[1.5ex]
      minimize   & $\left(\mathbf{q}^{1/\alpha}\right)^\top\!\mathbf{X}\mathbf{w}$  \\
      subject to & $\mathbf{q}^\top\mathbf{1}=1$ \\
                 & $\mathbf{q}\geq\mathbf{0}$
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{\fill}

\bigskip

Reference to: problem~\eqref{pr:1} and problem~\eqref{pr:2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the advantage of tabular wrt array?

Comment: @Patricio I updated the code because `equation*` was no longer required. Both `array` and `tabular` format data in a table but `array` requires math environment and consider cells as math expressions by default. Other than that, they do the same thing. However, if you mix text and math, I would choose `tabular`. It's more convenient to add `$...$` for math expressions rather than `\textup` or `\textrm` for text.

Comment: As to the outer `minipage`, it simply reduces the overall width for both groups (see `0.8\linewidth` in the code). I thought you complained about excessive space. This is just one way to make both groups look tighter.